# R - Setting margins does not work

Tags: r, plot, quantile-regression

I estimated a linear regression model by using the `quantreg` package. I now want to display the results graphically by using the `plot()` function:

```
plottest = plot(summary(QReg_final), parm=2,  main="y",ylab="jjjjj")
```

The result is the following (I can only link the image yet):

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yqe2t.png)

As you can see at the very left, the description of the y-axis is cut off. I then tried to adjust the margin parameters, but it seems to have zero influence on the plot. For example:

```
par(mar=c(10,10,2,2))
```

When I now run the above mentioned code, it results in the exact same plot. On the other hand, when plotting simple data (and not `summary()` of a quantile regression `rq()`) the margins are adjusted and the plot displays the new vector of margins.

I would appreciate help on this. Thank you.

Comment: It's easier to help if you supply a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) show where exactly you tried to set `par()` in relation to your plotting code. Also `par()` only works for base graphics functions and it's possible that `quantreg` uses non-base plotting functions.

Comment: Instead of using `par`  try adding `mar=c(10,10,2,2)` directly in the `plot` statement.

Comment: @MrFlick thank you for the reminder, I will do next time. The problem is solved now so I guess there is no need.

Comment: @G5W that worked! Thank you - why does this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `par` put `mar=c(10,10,2,2)` directly in the plot statement.

Many R packages provide customized versions of `plot` for their objects and these customized versions may set some of the graphical parameters. If you look at the documentation for `plot.summary.rqs`, it has its own `mar` parameter. If you set `mar` within the function call, it passes your value through to the base graphics `plot`. But if you set it using `par`, the customized `plot` overrides your setting. The documentation says "Suitable defaults are chosen based on the coefficients to be visualized".